# How to open page in <div> using ID with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing a single page application phonegap project. I have a page called #pageAdd. Inside #pageAdd, I have a form and if the form is valid, then I want to open #pageView using the id. How can I do that in submithandler? I tried but I'm not sure of the right way to call #pageView.

HTML

```
 <div data-role="page" id="pageAdd">

    <div data-role="header">

        <h2>Hello</h2>
    </div>
    <!-- main -->

    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">

        <form id="myform" class="validate">
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        Name : <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter Name" class="required"/>
        </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        Location : <input type="text" id="loc" placeholder="Enter Location" />
        </div>

        <div class="ui-body ui-body-b">
        <button type="submit" id="but_submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
        </form>


    </div>

    <!-- footer -->
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h2>mine</h2>
    </div>

</div>
<div data-role="page" id="pageView">
    <div data-role="header">

        <h2>View</h2>

    </div>
    <!-- main -->
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">

    </div>
    <!-- footer -->
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h2>mine</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$("#myform").validate({
submitHandler: function(form) {

location.href=$('#pageView');
}
});
```

Comment: You need to show more of your html - but basically, when form submitted, hide the form, show the view - do not use `location.href` as this then stops it being a SPA (and won't work the way you're trying anyway)

Comment: what should I use instead of location.href?

Comment: It's really hard without seeing more code or knowing your true goals but something like: `$('#pageAdd').hide(); $('#pageView').show();` will work, but this is basic and doesn't assume anything like contents of form, what gets returned etc etc

Comment: Thank you, that works. But it messed up my ui. It just showing like normal html page, my jquery classes not working.